# Insert nearby input's value in link using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input and a nearby link, and I would like to use JS to get the value from the input and insert it into the "mailto" element of the link. How can I accomplish this?

```
    '<input class="an-input" type="text" id="'+$.fn.dataTable.Editor.safeId(conf.id)+'">'+
    '<a class="ui-state-default inputButton an-button" href="mailto:">SEND</a>'
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a place where people just give you the code. You have to show you have at least attempted it

Comment: @CarkMarkham inb4 someone posts full code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
jQuery(function($){
  var inputVal = $('input').val();
  $('a').attr('href','mailto:'+ inputVal);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($){

   $('.an-button').click(function(e){

      $(this).attr('href', 'mailto:'+$('.an-input').val());

   }

});
```

Comment: He didn't asked to fire the function on click

Comment: Point taken, I kind of assumed. Gut feeling. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = $(".an-input");

$input.next(".an-button").attr("href", "mailto:" + $input.val());
```

Comment: `closest` only looks up the parents

Comment: this will not work you should write a code which works in all the situation

Comment: ooops, sorry. its pretty late here. i'd better go to bed, than write bad examples. 
edited my answer. thanks for pointing my face in !